# Disabling assert macro in C++

Tags: c++, macros, assert

I'm trying to disable the assert macro in C++ in this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf */
#include <assert.h>     /* assert */

#define NDEBUG

void print_number(int* myInt) {
  assert (myInt != NULL);
  printf ("%d\n", *myInt);
}

int main ()
{
  int a = 10;
  int * b = NULL;
  int * c = NULL;

  b = &a;

  print_number (b);
  print_number (c);

  return 0;
}
```

The [official website](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cassert/assert/) says that if I define NDEBUG, all the assert macro will be disable. This way [doesn't work](http://cpp.sh/2x6ow). Can you tell me how fix it?

Comment: You have to define `NDEBUG` before including `<assert.h>`.

Comment: cplusplus.com is not the official website of C++. The only truly official documentation of C++ is the C++ standard. Websites such as cplusplus.com and cppreference.com offer interpretations of the C++ standard, and since cplusplus.com is known for containing errors I would recommend you use cppreference.com. If you read the page you linked to carefully, it says that you must define `NDEBUG` before you include the header.

Comment: You might want to use the C++ headers `<cstdio>` and `<cassert>`.

Comment: A common way is to do this from the command line. That way you don't have to change your code between when making debug and release builds. For `g++` and `clang++` you'd add `-DNDEBUG` to get a build without `assert`s.

Comment: The `<cassert>` header is one of the few headers that is not idempotent.  So just after the `#define NDEBUG` do a `#include <cassert>` and you'll be golden.  You can enable/disable the assert macro multiple times in your translation unit by doing a `#define NDEBUG` and `#undef NDEBUG` and then `#include` it again and again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `NDEBUG` define controls the definition of the `assert` macro, not its expansion.  In order for it to be effective, you need to define it *before* the macro itself is defined, which happens in `assert.h`.

There are two ways to achieve that:

- put the `#define NDEBUG` before the line that says `#include <assert.h>`; or
- define `NDEBUG` on the command line, by doing something like:

```
cc -DNDEBUG main.c
```

Perhaps you should also take a step back and consider why you are trying to disable assertions.  After all, the assertions are there for a reason, so unless you are running on a 40MHz SPARCstation, you should probably not be disabling them.

Comment: Note by the way that your code is good old C.  Why did you tag your question as C++?